# Multiple group using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm wanting to get the sum of all events for each company. Here is my data:

```
{company: "1" event:"a"}
{company: "1" event:"b"}
{company: "1" event:"c"}
{company: "2" event:"b"}
{company: "2" event:"b"}
{company: "3" event:"c"}
{company: "3" event:"c"}
```

I currently have this to aggregate the date for events but I'm struggling to further group them by company:

```
{
  "aggregate": [

    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": "$event",
        "count": {"$sum": 1}
      }
    },
    {"$sort": {"_id": 1}}
  ]
}
```

Which renders these results:

[
    {
        "_id": "a",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": "b",
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "_id": "c",
        "count": 2
    }]

How can I further group the event counts by company to produce something along the lines of:

```
 [{
        "_id": {
            "company" :"1",
            "events": [
                {
                    "event": "a",
                    "count": 1
                },
                {
                    "event": "b",
                    "count": 1
                },
                {
                    "event": "c",
                    "count": 1
                },
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "company" :"2",
            "events": [
                {
                    "event": "b",
                    "count": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "company" :"3",
            "events": [
                {
                    "event": "c",
                    "count": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    ]
```

I've tried all sorts of further groups in the query but can't produce the data I'm after. There is also one caveat: I'm unable to process anything server side or change the schema, so therefore I am only enable to pass in a query which I hope can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $group:{
     _id:{company:"$company",event:"$event"},
     count:{$sum:1}
  }
},
{
  $group:{
     _id:"$_id.company",
     events:{$push:{event:"$_id.event",count:"$count"}}
  }
}
])
```

And if u need exact same output you mentioned then add $project stage like

$project:{_id:{company:"$_id",events:"$events"}}

Comment: Great stuff thanks. So the first group sets the groups to parse and the next group says for each company push the events for that company and group by event id and get the count